# GA4 - Google Data Studio - Specific Event Metrics

Tags: google-analytics, metrics, looker-studio, google-analytics-4

I am needing to break down Event Count by specific events. I know that for a single tile I could add a filter for `Event Name` and display that way, however in a table format such as the one below, I cannot seem to create specific event metrics.

[image]

I've tried everything I could find as well as creating a new metric specific to checking for a certain event and attempting to sum all occurrences of this:
is_social_link_click:

```
CASE
  WHEN (Event name='link_click_social') THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

count_social_link_clicks:

```
SUM(is social link click)
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I've also tried Data Export, along with the following setup, which gives me what I want. However I need to be able to dynamically update the date range, and Data Exports don't allow for that.

```
CASE
  WHEN (Event name='link_click_social') THEN Event count
  ELSE 0
END
```

I've also tried data blending, and adding 4 tables of the same data and applying the custom filter to each one, however I'm not sure that they're properly sharing the Session medium dimension such that they can be broken down per Session medium.

How can this be accomplished?

Thanks

UPDATE:
I
I've managed to create something close to what I need by:

1. creating 4 tables, one for Resource Page Visit filtered by Session medium, one for Contact Form Submit filtered by Session medium, ...etc.
2. ctrl clicking to select them all and right click -> Blend Data (which sets Session Medium as a join key).

The problem with this is that it only displays events if all 4 tables(events) had an event from each medium in question. So for example, if all 4 had an event come from `referral` we're good, but if only Resource Page Visit had an event from referral, then this data will be dropped since the other tables(events) don't share at least one instance of this source.

Comment: great UPDATE: I I've managed to create something close to what I need by

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand your question correctly, but it looks like you need to add session medium and event name as dimensions and event count as a metric, and that will break down the data

Comment: I guess my issue is needing to create a specific metric for each event, or at least conversion events. I get what you're saying and I've used that strategy in the past, but I'm looking for something more like UA where there are 20 or so metrics (previously goals) that could be used directly. 

A use case where this is needed is comparing the number of occurrences of a specific event vs another specific event in a table. And also for further data aggregation, it was helpful to have prebuilt metrics.

Comment: I need to be able to define a new metric, rather than using a filter on totalEvents (since you cant apply filters per column in tables) and use that metric.

Comment: There is a possibility to create custom dimensions (value is not a number) and custom metrics (value is a number) in Analytics
Go to Configure tab and choose Custom definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something very similar. Specifically, I wanted to be able to report on on-site searches as a metric alongside other metrics. Here is what I came up with:
First, add an event_count parameter to the event, and set the value to 1 - below is a screenshot of the event config in Tag Manager. Note that I disabled the automatic 'search' event in GA4 admin in this case so there would not be any double counting.

[image: Screenshot of GTM configuration screen for search event, showing search_count parameter with Value set to 1]

Then add a custom metric in GTM to capture the parameter.

[image: Screenshot of GA4 custom metric configuration screen: Metric name equals "Searches", Scope is Event, Event parameter is "search_count", and Unit of measurement is Standard]

Then you will be able to use the metric you created in GA4 Explorations or Data Studio reports.